# How to copy files from source to destination if the file size is more than 0 KB?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file which is generated by an external program. If the file size is greater than 0 KB, then the file should be copied to other location: Otherwise if the file is 0 KB, it the copy command should be skipped.

According to advice provided in the comment area, *(since deleted)*, I tried:

```
for %%I in ("C:\Program Files\Test.txt") do if %%~zI GTR 1023 copy /Y "%%I" "C:\"
```

But it did not work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would offer you the [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) command:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%RoboCopy.exe" "Source" "Destination" "File(s)" /Min:1
```

*Please open a Command Prompt window and enter `"%__appdir__%roboCopy.exe" /?` to read its usage information.*

**[Edit /]**

Using the example, provided by way of edit to your question, perhaps this would work:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%RoboCopy.exe" "C:\Program Files" "C:\." "Test.txt" /Min:1
```

If you can be sure that the default locations are still in place under `%PATH%` and the default extensions are untouched under `%PATHEXT%`, you could change `"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe"` to just `RoboCopy`.

Comment: As a side note to the above, normal user accounts do not generally have permission to write to the root of the system drive, so if that is your real intention, you'll most likely find that running the script As administrator will help.